# How to create dependencies on specific version of a package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

recently I faced issues due to changes in rosapi version installed by standard ros installation command.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

In the new version the name of rosapi package executable is changed. Is there any way where I can specify external package version my package depends on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207735/how-to-create-dependencies-on-specific-version-of-a-package/) by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is documented in [REP-127](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html) (for pkg format 1) and [REP-140](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html) for pkg format 2. From the [build-depend (multiple)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#build-depend-multiple) section:

> All dependencies and relationships may restrict their applicability to particular versions. For each comparison operator an attribute can be used. Two of these attributes can be used together to describe a version range.

> `version_lt="VERSION" (optional)`

> The dependency to the package is restricted to versions less than the stated version number.

> `version_lte="VERSION" (optional)`

> The dependency to the package is restricted to versions less or equal than the stated version number.

> `version_eq="VERSION" (optional)`

> The dependency to the package is restricted to a version equal than the stated version number.

> `version_gte="VERSION" (optional)`

> The dependency to the package is restricted to versions greater or equal than the stated version number.

> `version_gt="VERSION" (optional)`

> The dependency to the package is restricted to versions greater than the stated version number.

This is for pkg format 1, but it is the same for [format 2](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#build-depend-multiple).

However, as far as I can tell, I don't think you can use this for your specific use case:

> In the new version the name of rosapi package executable is changed. Is there any way where I can specify external package version my package depends on?

While you can specify that your `my-pkg-A.B` depends on `some-pkg-X.Y`, there is no way for users installing from the current package repositories to actually retrieve that version as soon as `some-pkg` has been updated (say to version `X.Z`). Only a single version is ever retained on the package repositories, so `some-pkg-X.Z`, the latest. Specifying a `version_eq` (or `version_lt`) requirement will now result in your `my-pkg-A.B` being uninstallable, as its dependencies cannot be satisfied (ie: there is no longer a `some-pkg-X.Y` on the servers which is needed for `my-pkg-A.B`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) on 2015-04-24**:
Thats what I imagined. Thank you for confirming this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-25**:
It would however prevent users from installing your package and then finding out it doesn't work. In some scenarios, that is better than not checking at all. Also: for from-source installs this would work, as you can just checkout a specific version / tag.